# How can I make my CRONTAB point to another version of php

Tags: php, cron, centos

I am using cron to run a php service. My cron points to php 5.6.2 while the cli mode points to 5.5.3.

May I know, how cam I make my cron point to php 5.5.3. ??????

I echo-ed phpversion() in the file that I am calling via cron, it echoes 5.6.2 while the same file echoes 5.5.3 when I run it via command line (not via cron)

Thanks!

Comment: It is likely to be an alias of some sort. Can you type ``which php`` on the command line and add the response?

Comment: @ockcyp thanks for the comment. It gives the directory basically on centos /usr/local/bin/php  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the full path of the PHP executable you use on command line by executing:

```
which php
```

Assuming the response is `/usr/local/bin/php`, you can specify that path in crontab.

Example:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```